# How to copy file from PC to Mac, while preserving xattrs on the target file?

Tags: windows-7, macos, rsync, file-transfer, file-attributes

I've a file M on my Mac (OS X ML 10.8.4) and file P on my PC (Win7). File P was originally a copy of file M but is now slightly updated. File M has some extended attributes.

How can I copy file P onto file M, while preserving the extended attributes on file M?

Generally if I copy-paste P onto M through network share, the extended attributes on M are lost.

I'm looking for a an easily implementable / scalable way. `cat P > M`  is not really an option (not even sure if that works). Could `rsync` help here?

Answer (score 2):

If there are still ._ files, you can merge them with dot_clean:

```
$ ls -A
._test.txt test.txt
$ xattr -l test.txt
$ dot_clean .
$ ls -A
test.txt
$ xattr -l test.txt
com.apple.TextEncoding: utf-8;134217984
```

You can copy attributes with xattr -wx and -px:

```
xattr -wx attributename "$(xattr -px attributename source.txt)" target.txt
```

xattr only prints attribute names if the argument is a single file:

```
for f; do
  for a in $(xattr "$f"); do
    xattr -wx $a "$(xattr -px $a ~/Documents/Original/"$f")" "$f"
  done
done
```

Comment: +1 for the hint regarding `dot_clean` to get `._file.txt`to the xattr of `file.txt`. Did not have the same problem as the OP but may help for my issue at hand. Thanks!